# Application didreceiveRemoteNotification and jumping to a specific view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, push-notification

I have been trying everything to work this out. I get a notification when the app is closed with 2 custom items, a type and an id. The type is supposed to tell me which view to load, and the id is supposed to tell the app which row to get from the database. I am going through hell trying to figure this out.

I need to click on the notification and have it take me to the relevant record. So far I have been almost successful with two different methods that I'll outline below.

I should also point out that I know the payload is working correctly from APNS as I've debugged it to death :)

The first thing I tried was as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSString *itemType = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"T"] description];
    NSString *itemId = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"] description];

    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // type 1 = call, type 2 = contact
    if ([itemType isEqual: @"1"]) {
        Leads_CallsDetailViewController *callView = [[Leads_CallsDetailViewController alloc] init];
        [callView displayItem:itemId];
        [self.window addSubview:callView.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else if([itemType isEqual: @"2"]) {
        Leads_ContactsDetailViewController *contactView = [[Leads_ContactsDetailViewController alloc] init];
        [contactView displayItem:itemId];
        [self.window addSubview:contactView.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

With this one, I have a method on the detail views called displayItem that I was going to use to get the data from the api and then display it. This did something, but it looked like the view never really loaded. I have a scrollview and various buttons on the page, but all that ever got loaded from addSubview was a background image. Nothing ever really happened to  fully load the view. I wasn't sure how to handle that.

The second thing I tried was to go directly to the view like this:

```
NSString *storyboardId = @"Leads_Calls_SB";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = initViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This one seems to load the view functioning and nice looking with two major caveats. 1. I'm not sure how to pass data to it, and 2. It didn't like it when I tried to pop back and it also got angry when I tried to segue pushes from there, almost as if there was no navigation controller for the view, even though the entire application is embedded in a navigation controller.

Thanks so much for your help. If anyone can help me figure this out I'll be indebted to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally for this requirement I would do this..

1. Use NSNotificationCenter and post a notification from didReceiveRemoteNotification.

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationReceived"     object:self userInfo:userInfo];
   ```
2. Subscribe to it from the VC from where you can open your details view to show the message.

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived:) name:@"notificationReceived" object:nil];
   ```
3. If you are instantiating the VC yourself and not using segue. you can do this..

   ```
   UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   detailVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
   detailVC.delegate = self;

   detailVC.userInfo = @"YOUR DATA";
   [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
4. To return you can do this in your detail VC..

   ```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

Comment: Cool. I'll be working on this tomorrow and just had one more question. I was trying to read up on the NSNotificationCenter and I'm confused as to what exactly this does. When I click on notification, I want to create a notification center with the name notificationReceived correct? Then from there, I create a listener on my detail view. Then I present the detail view. How does the actual passing of data happen in NSNotificationCenter? Or do I just pass in data from userInfo? If the latter, then what do I need NSNotificationCenter for. Sorry if that's a pain, just trying to understand! :D

Comment: Hi Chris, NSNotificationCenter has a publisher subscriber pattern. you can pass data using userInfo parameter. The beauty about NSNotificationCenter is that it makes your app loosely coupled and passing data happens without having a direct reference between sender and receiver.