# Objective-C: How to Handle an iOS push notification properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented everything correctly in my app to receive push notifications, i'm receiving the notifications just fine, but how can i do something when the user clicks on it?

Here's my code regarding the matter:

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    NSLog(@"Hello from appDelegate");
}
```

It's working, i'm getting the userInfo and the other message in my Xcode log.

Now i want to do something (go to a specific segue) when the user clicks on the notification. I have seen the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) but it's very complicated and hard to follow.

I just need to know what function to use in the MainViewController.m

Any hints? thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499009/3800154 what about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post notifications (Using `NSNotificationCenter`) from `AppDelegate` on different events and then add observer in particular classes where ever you want to perform a particular operation.

**Code Implementation**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSString *aStrEventType = userInfo[@"eventType"];
    if ([aStrEventType isEqualToString:@"callWebService"]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"callWebService" object:nil];
    }else{
        // Implement other notification here
    }
}
```

Now in your particular class you can handle notification as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:@"" selector:@selector(callMyWebService) name:nil object:nil];
}
-(void)callMyWebService{
      //Perform your action.
}
```

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to perform.

Comment: I'm sending a push notification with an artilce_id, i want to get this article_id and perform a particular segue

Comment: Are you on the screen from where you want to push the segue? I mean make sure that you are not on some other screen and then want to push from somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98914/discussion-between-fadi-obaji-and-rahul-mathur).