# UINavigationBar is hidden when app launch with push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have a `ViewController`. Normally I initiate it with

```
MyBookingDetailedViewController * vcNavigate = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyBookingDetailedViewController"];
vcNavigate.bookId = [booking.bookingId intValue];
vcNavigate.status = booking.bookingStatus;
```

Now I'm trying to open it with when user click `pushNotification`. What i have done is I added this following in `didRecieveRemoteNotification` in `AppDelegate` file.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

MyBookingDetailedViewController *booking = (MyBookingDetailedViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyBookingDetailedViewController"];
booking.bookId = [notificationId intValue];
booking.status = notificationStatus;

[navigationController pushViewController:booking animated:YES];
```

but when it appears, the top navigation bar is hidden. I cant go back, it's just view only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found proper answer how to handle Push Notification to load page. it is using `NSNotificationCenter`

[Application didreceiveRemoteNotification and jumping to a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498085/application-didreceiveremotenotification-and-jumping-to-a-specific-view)

Answer (score 0):

You can put below code in **MyBookingDetailedViewController**

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: what is difference between answer given by @Vikita and your answer? Its looks completely copied.

Comment: She edited her answer before that she set navigation bar hidden as YES. I am really scared of those people who down vote your answer without knowing the history. I don't copy answers you can view my history.

Answer (score 0):

please use below code and apply this code in view will appear it may be help you..

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
```